# Unable to find a target named `<Workspace Name>` in project `Xtreme.xcodeproj`

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, cocoapods, xcode10

i'm working on swift 3 project with xcode 10.1, i have a requirement to install few pods (firebase/crashlytics), however when i trigger the pod install it seems to return the following error message. the previous used the same pod file and the project is running perfectly. the only issue is with installing new pods. anyone can help?

Get-R-Done -: Workspace name
Xtreme -: Project name

Pod File

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Get-R-Done' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
   pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.1'
   pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 2.1'
   pod 'ALCameraViewController'
   pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
   pod 'ILPDFKit', '~> 1.0'
   pod 'Fabric'
   pod 'Crashlytics'
   pod 'ActiveLabel', '~> 0.7'
   # Add the pod for Firebase Crashlytics
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

# Recommended: Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'  


  # Pods for Get-R-Done

  target 'Get-R-DoneTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Get-R-DoneUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Error message that i get

```
[!] Unable to find a target named `Get-R-Done` in project `Xtreme.xcodeproj`, did find `Xtreme`, `XtremeTests`, and `XtremeUITests`.
```

Comment: Do you have a target named 'Get-R-Done' in your project settings?

Comment: Target names looks 'Xtreme', and not 'Get-R-Done', i have changed pods file into 'Xtreme' but it seems project creates another work space and can not work with current one. i want to install the pods into current workspace

Comment: You can specify a workspace with "workspace 'MyWorkspace'" in the top level of the pod file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to Swift 4 and resolved isseue